# Is there any way to access the AsyncTask object in a class ,after exiting the App?

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-asynctask

I am newbie to Android and Java and I want to know how to access the AsyncTask object after exiting the App. Can anyone help?. My need is to cancel an Image upload doing in the background of `AsyncTask` when clicking the progress bar Notification after exiting the App (like facebook image upload). I have searched for that, but I didn't get find a possible solution for that.

```
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
        pd = new ProgressDialog(ImageUploadActivity.this);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setMessage("Uploading Picture...");
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        pd.setCancelable(true);
        pd.show();
        pd.setProgress(0);

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // updating progress bar value
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        pd.setProgress((int) (progress[0]));
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);
        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            /* entity.addPart("uploaded_file", new ByteArrayBody(data,
                        "myImage.jpg"));*/

            File sourceFile = new File(picturePath);
            entity.addPart("uploaded_file",  new FileBody(sourceFile));
            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
            response=responseString;
        }
        return responseString;
        // return response;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

        // showing the server response in an alert dialog
        //showAlert(result);
        serverCheck(result);
        if(isInternetPresent==false) {
            mBuilder.setContentText("Turn on Internet");
        }
        else {
            mBuilder.setContentText("Upload Complete");

            playSound();
            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            progressBarNotificationComplete();
        }
        // mBuilder.setContentText("Upload Complete");
        // Removes the progress bar
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        pd.dismiss();

        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

I have a progress bar notification that will notify when upload starts.

My notification

```
 public void progressBarNotificationComplete() {
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ImageUploadActivity.this);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Upload")
            .setContentText("Upload Completed")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    // mBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, false);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ImageUploadActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("FROM_NOTIFICATION", true);
    // notificationIntent.putExtra("first_state", 2);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "pendingintent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mNotifyManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Here the pending intent will call the upload activity, I have an alert dialogue in Upload activity to cancel the upload. This is working fine before I am exiting the app. But if I exit the app I know that the Activity will be destroyed and upload will be done in background. What can I do if I want to cancel the upload? I have tried intent service, but intent service stop only after completing each intent requests. And I have also tried background service. So I wrote the code for network connection in a thread and I have tried to stop that thread when cancel button clicked, but it did not work. I am very disappointed. What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: You need provide as much code as possible with your question along with what you've already tried

Comment: Well one thing I can think, of is having a kind of global class that you can get its instance of.  And by adding a value such as isSendTrue, then send photo if its true and just bring down the progress bar if its not, and at the last step before you send your file out check to see if the value is set to send. I did something similar but mine was set if photo address is null, it became null after a view was dismissed.

Comment: Can you give  a sample code? .I read about Global class.I am jzt trying to do  that :), if you give a sample code, it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: @ Ashley : How can i access global class instances after exiting the app

Answer (score 0):

Cancel your task in the onStop method of the activity.

Read more about activity lifecycles here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

The other way is to move your long running processes to a service which will continue in the background even if the application is closed giving you more control over long running processes (For example cancel long running processes when activity dies).